# Submit button does not work, how to make it work? (code provided in description)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make this code work, and have tried many things (some of which I also found in StackOverflow), but nothing works. When I click on "Send Message" (submit button to send the contact info), absolutely nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<!-- CONTACT FORM -->
                     <form method="post" class="wow fadeInUp" id="contact-form">

                          <!-- IF MAIL SENT SUCCESSFUL -->
                          <h6 class="text-success">Your message has been sent successfully.</h6>

                          <!-- IF MAIL NOT SENT -->
                          <h6 class="text-danger">E-mail must be valid and message must be longer than 1 character.</h6>

                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cf-name" name="name" placeholder="Full name">
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                               <input type="email" class="form-control" id="cf-email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cf-subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">

                               <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="cf-message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

                               <button type="submit" class="form-control" id="cf-submit" name="submit">Send Message</button>
                          </div>
                     </form>
```

JS:

```
// CONTACT FORM
$("#contact-form").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#cf-name").val();
  var email = $("#cf-email").val();
  var subject = $("#cf-subject").val();
  var message = $("#cf-message").val();
  var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message;

  function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
  };
  if (isValidEmail(email) && (message.length > 1) && (name.length > 1)) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "contact.php"
          data: dataString,
          success: function () {
              $('.text-success').fadeIn(1000);
              //$('.text-danger').fadeOut(500);
          }
      });
  }
  else {
      $('.text-danger').fadeIn(1000);
      //$('.text-success').fadeOut(500);
  }
  return false;
});
```

contact.php:

```
<?php
 if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && 
 isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

 // detect & prevent header injections
 $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
 foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
 if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
  exit;
}
}


mail( "davidchau@gmail.com", "Contact Form: ". $_POST['name'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] );
}
?>
```

I have the JS script inside the body of the HTML (at the end of the body). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not sending the form data in the correct way

Comment: Check this resource https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-jquery-ajax-post-request-exampleexample.html#:~:text=you%20can%20simply%20form%20submit,to%20post%20method%20with%20php.

Comment: You're sending the AJAX call with POST  method, but formatting the data like for GET request. Make `dataString` to an object instead of the string, that way jQuery handles the correct format.

Comment: data: dataString should be data: { name, email, subject, message } with data type json

Comment: Add an error handler to the ajax call...

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Tried to input the other website stuff but did not manage to successfully do it.

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean?

Comment: @epascarello would you mind writing the code for your suggestion? I am new to programming and I am trying to learn. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Update the question with latest code that you are saying is not successful. And do check the network tab in chrome to see if the api call is happening or not.

Comment: Convert dataString to an object like this:
var dataString = { name: name, email: email, subject: subject, message: message };